# How to increase font size of first letter in each word on a sentence automatic in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm trying to do that in automatically way:

[image]

Is possible in MS Word?

Comment: Would you be using all-caps or is that just an example?

Comment: Why don't you just use a font with small caps, or all caps

Comment: I have been found this style on some papers in web and specially in Brazil's master dissertations, so I wanted to use. I wondering that is a common style.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if anyone is still looking for a solution or not but I'll still reply, just in case.

1. Go to Styles and right click on any one (I usually choose a heading style) and click on "Modify".
2. At the bottom-left of the Modify Style window, click Format>Font
3. In the "Effects" section of the Font window, check Small Caps and click OK

That's all you have to do.

Now just highlight the content where you want to apply the style and select the style from the ribbon on the top.

[image: Small caps font formatting]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: note that you can just select arbitrary text and press Ctrl+D to format font then select small caps

Answer (score 0):

Preparation:
Make sure that "Grow font" and "Shrink font" appears in any toolbar, or in the custom tool bar for Word versions using a "Ribbon".
*I do not have WORD installed, to allow to create images required for a better description*

1. Then place the cursor before the first character of a word you wish
   to "InitialCapsify".
2. Find "Record new macro" (Developer tab in the Ribbon, menu entry for
   older Word) - set a shortcut key as you activate macro recording.
3. Hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and move the cursor right one character - the character
   will become selected.
4. Click once on the "Grow font" icon in the toolbar (to grow the char
   one pt, click more for larger change).
5. Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and attempt to move cursor right (the cursor moves to next
   word), make any adjustment to place it just before the first char in
   that word.
6. End the macro recording.

Now pressing the shortcut key will run the macro and set the effect on the next word, repeat the shortcut-key press for each additional word you wish the effect on.

Comment: Thanks @Hannu for ans.I know this way, by the way is necessary enable macro support in word file (.DOCM). But if I have a text with 1000 words? I want a macro that when I select the all text it makes the magic, do you get it?

Comment: Well then, the macro you get above is the very basics of that. All you need is to do some googling on how to loop through the selected words, then edit it accordingly.